# MongoDB get list of item.field in array of items

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I posted a question yesterday - that, because if not knowing "how" to ask, it was poorly presented - So if you recognize the structure/data, please re-read, I hope I am able to present it in a clearer manner.

I want to return an array of items from multiple nested arrays of objects.

My ultimate goal is something that look like this...

```
{person:1, cost: ['23,543','56,556','8,500']},
{person:2, cost: []}
```

This lets me know 2 pieces of information, 1- it allows me to total across two or more arrays of objects, and 2- it lets me see persons who have NOT filled in information.

The Scenario:

I have a couple array of objects, and I want to find out if people are filling in 'cost' on an object.

So a model that looks like this.

```
person : {
    my_cars: [
        {
            make:
            model:
            cost:
        }
    ],
    my_motorcycles: [
        {
            make:
            model:
            cost:
        }
    ]
}
```

Some data will look like this (and this data corresponds to my above desired result...)

```
person : {
    _id: 1
    ,my_cars: [
        {
            make: 'ford'
            model: 'taurus'
            cost: null
        },
        {
            make: 'ford'
            model: 'mustang'
            cost:'23,543'
        }
        ,{
            make: 'lincoln'
            model: 'navigator'
            cost: '56,556'
        }
    ]
    ,my_motorcycles: [
        {
            make: 'ducati'
            model: ''
            cost: '8,500'
        }
        ,{
            make: 'yamaha'
            model: 'v-star 650'
            cost: ''
        }
    ]
}
,person : {
    _id: 2
    ,my_cars: [
        {
            make: 'ford'
            model: 'taurus'
            cost: null
        },
        ,{
            make: 'chevy'
            model: 'chevette'
            cost: null
        }
    ]
    ,my_motorcycles: [
        {
            make: 'harley-davidson'
            model: 'softtail'
            cost: ''
        }
        ,{
            make: 'honda'
            model: 'x650'
            cost: ''
        }
    ]
}
```

So what I am trying to do is unwind
but if I try

```
$unwind{
    path: "$my_cars.cost"
}
,$unwind{
    path: "$my_motorcycles.cost"
}
```

this is not working...

Any help on getting to an output close to knowing the Number of an instance of a field in multiple nested arrays is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of non-empty values can be retrieved after [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) run on both arrays ([$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html)). You can use [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/index.html) to check if value is a string:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            person: "$_id",                
            cost: {
                $filter: {
                    input: { $concatArrays: [ "$my_cars.cost", "$my_motorcycles.cost" ] },
                    cond: {
                        $and: [
                            { $eq: [ { $type: "$$this" }, "string" ] },
                            { $ne: [ "$$this", "" ] }
                        ]
                    }                           
                }
            }                        
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cBCmn0g1SHZ)

Comment: Perfect - thx Mickl - I had tried this - but it did not work. $project: {
       email:1,
       cost: { 
           $filter: {
             input: { $concatArrays: [ '$my_cars.cost', '$vidPS', '$my_motorcycles.cost' ] },
             as: "x",
             cond: { '$$x': { $nin: [ null, "" ] } }
          } - your solution worked...  can you explain "$$this"

Comment: @jpmyob `$$this` simply refers to currently processed array element so it will be subsequent costs in this case